# На некоторых сайтах не работает колесико мышки. Как это реализуется?

Tags: браузер

Имеет ввиду быстрая прокрутка при нажатии на колесико, чтобы быстро перемотать страницу.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нажатие на колесико идентично клику средней кнопки на старых мышках. То есть по сути щелкая кнопкой мыши врубаем режим быстрой навигации где mousemove срабатывает как ускоренный скролл, а выход осуществляется по клику любой кнопки мыши.

Comment: это фича браузера, а не сайта =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel - Плагин jquery для работы с колесиком

Не тестировал, но скроллинг, наверное, можно отключить так

```
$(document).mousewheel(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); //Используем это или то, что ниже для отключения стандартного события
      //Ваш код
      //return 0;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).mousewheel(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //Используем это или то, что ниже для отключения стандартного события
  //Ваш код
  //return 0;
});
```

Вставлять в `index.php` или в `index.html` после сразу после `<body>`

Comment: Это что за прикол?

Comment: Похоже, что ваш ответ почти полностью повторяет [соседний](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/74451/181472). В этом случае было бы лучше не повторять его, а [дополнить правкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/74451/edit).